# ModelState.AddModelError is setup to display Canned message instead of real Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my website i had a group of people working on my site and i have this code that they put a canned message in for an error. When i debug the code it is actually a different error but displays this canned message. For instance when i put the information in the form i used an email address that already exists in the database but it is showing a message to check the password requirements. How can this be fixed to show the actual error. To me it also seems like there is a lot code going on in this that may not need to be or can be achieved cleaner Your thoughts?

Code of Post Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateCompanyUser(ExpandedUserDTO ExpandedUserDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ExpandedUserDTO == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var Email = ExpandedUserDTO.Email.Trim();
            var UserName = ExpandedUserDTO.UserName.Trim();
            var Password = ExpandedUserDTO.Password.Trim();

            if (UserName == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("No Username");
            }

            if (Password == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("No Password");
            }

            // UserName is LowerCase of the Email
            // UserName = Email.ToLower();

            // Create user

            var objNewAdminUser = new Models.ApplicationUser { UserName = UserName, Email = Email };
            var AdminUserCreateResult = UserManager.Create(objNewAdminUser, Password);

            if (AdminUserCreateResult.Succeeded == true)
            {
                string strNewRole = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["Roles"]);

                if (strNewRole != "0")
                {
                    // Put user in role
                    UserManager.AddToRole(objNewAdminUser.Id, strNewRole);
                }
                var viewModel = new Users();
                {
                    viewModel.UsersId = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());
                    viewModel.Email = Email;
                    viewModel.FirstName = UserName;
                    viewModel.AspNetUsersId = objNewAdminUser.Id;
                    viewModel.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                    viewModel.UpdatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                };
                UsersBusinessModels Login = new UsersBusinessModels();
                var results = Login.insertUserWithougAsny(viewModel);

                string[] roleRemove = new string[2] { "Administrator", "CompanyAdmin" };
                ViewBag.Roles = GetAllRolesAsSelectList().Where(k => !roleRemove.Contains(k.Text)).ToList();

                // return RedirectToAction();
                Response.Redirect("/Customer/ManageUsers/" + User.Identity.GetUserId());
                return PartialView();
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Roles = GetAllRolesAsSelectList();
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
                    "Error: Failed to create the user. Check password requirements.");
                return PartialView(ExpandedUserDTO);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Roles = GetAllRolesAsSelectList();
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error: " + ex);
            string[] roleRemove = new string[2] { "Administrator", "CompanyAdmin" };
            ViewBag.Roles = GetAllRolesAsSelectList().Where(k => !roleRemove.Contains(k.Text)).ToList();

            return PartialView(ExpandedUserDTO);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Generally speaking, from a security perspective you *don't* want to tell a user that an email address is already used, doesn't exist, etc. - that leaks information about your users to someone who really shouldn't know that.

Comment: I do see your point. Then maybe i should make the message say something different. If that is why this was put in there i understand however it leads the person to continue to put different passwords in and eventually give up because they do not know the root of the cause.

Comment: However i have been on sites where i have been before and forgot that i had an account and tried to create one and the error said email already exists.

Comment: If a site told you that, they either made a conscious decision that the security practice didn't apply to them, or (more likely) they don't follow best practices (either because they don't know or because they don't deem them relevant).

Comment: It's up to you (or whomever makes these decisions) as to whether that's information you're comfortable disclosing (within reason; things like the GDPR impact what you're allowed to do / what your responsibilities are). OWASP maintains some guidance which you might find useful: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html. Troy Hunt's blog is generally good reading as well (here's a good example: https://www.troyhunt.com/passwords-evolved-authentication-guidance-for-the-modern-era/)

Comment: Thanks, however it still errors out even with new credentials. meaning none that match anything and also still adds it to the database. I changed the error for now but am still getting it and i checked the database and the user was successfully added. Also i fired the developers for this very reason there is a lot of wrong going on in my website. Unfortunately i paid dearly and am now paying because it is not right...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203942/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-scott-purtan).

Comment: do you want to show the error message below the input text? or show all errors in one section?